# How can I read and remove elements from a List<List<T>>?

Tags: java

I've obtained a list of lists from the cartesian product and now I need to remove all the elements that repeat 2 times the same letter and one of the elements that contain the same 2 letters in different order (gg, sg, gs)
here's my code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class partite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nomi = { "G", "S", "R" };
        List<List<String>> player = giocatori(nomi);
        System.out.println(player);
    }

    public static List<List<String>> giocatori(String[] players) {
        ArrayList<String> comb = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            comb.add(players[i]);
        }

        List<List<String>> list = Lists.cartesianProduct(comb, comb);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop the cartesion product entirely and start building the list from scratch yourself. Iterate over the players and in the body of iteration iterate over all player above the given index, that way you will not have `gg` and only `gs` but no `sg`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?